# { и [ прилипают к предыдущей строке

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, code-style

При форматировании документа `{` и `[` переносится на предыдущую строчку, если относится к ней. Например, массив, как аргумент в функции:

```js
start(arg, 
[
 1,
 2,
 3
])
```

После форматирования станет

```js
start(arg, [
 1,
 2,
 3
])
```

Но это не критично.

Вот, что критично:

```js
const a = 1,
 b = 2,
 { c, d } = obj,
 e = 4;
```

После форматирования станет:

```js
const a = 1,
 b = 2, { c, d } = obj,
 e = 4;
```

Как можно это исправить, не убирая самого форматирования?

Полазил в настройках vs code в emmet, но ничего не нашел.

Comment: Это должны быть 4 разных const. Или одна строка =)

Comment: @vp_arth, все-же хотелось бы решения...

Comment: Выбери другой форматор кода или измени настройки имеющегося, но это муторно...